# Flexslider slide with centered image in fixed aspect ratio div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexslider

I am using a theme which employs the [`flexheader`](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) to show banner images. Since it's a theme, I cannot really modify the options of the slide show directly and am trying to work around it.

What I want is height of the banner to stay the same. 16:9 images use the entire banner space, but lower aspect-ratio images are centered with solid background color around them.

So I am trying to pass a particularly styled div as list item (slide): I create 16:9 div and solid gray background.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/birnstiel/efjjwayk/1/) is an example, which mostly works, but the slide with the logo is stretched. How can I keep the image aspect ratio and keep the image in the horizontal center? Or is there a much easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to remove the `height: 100% !important` from the image element, because that piece of code is stretching it.

```
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: auto;
}
```

But the image wont be filling the whole slider area, as there will be a gap on both sides, but it wont be stretched. To make the images fill the whole slide, you would need to upload the image in the correct size. Hope you understood what I've meant.

Comment: yes, that's what I had in mind. Smaller images have borders on both sides while images that have the right size will be shown in full. Thanks!

Comment: hm, ok one more problem: if the image is actually too big, I want it to fill the entire width. I got that with `max-width:100%`, but that again squeezes it vertically.

Comment: Then you could center the image (there are plenty of examples on Stackoverflow) in the container, or try to upload each image with the same height.